# « Pile » ou « batterie »

Tags: choix-de-mot, québec

Quelle est la différence entre une pile et une batterie ?

Quand on parle d'une pile ordinaire (de type AA, C, 9V, ...), peut-on utiliser le terme  « batterie » ?

Quand on parle d'une batterie de voiture 12V, peut-on utiliser le terme « pile » ?

Des sites bilingues (comme walmart.ca) utilisent « batterie » quand on s'attend à ce qu'ils utilisent « pile ». Est-ce que les deux mots sont confondus dans le français canadien ?

Comment: Je met en commentaire, parce que je ne peux donner assez d'information pour une réponse complète. "Batterie" est utilisé au Québec là où on devrait dire "pile". L'utilisation de walmart.ca, qui se conforme au Français québécois, témoigne probablement de cette erreur commune afin de mieux communiquer avec le public cible.

Comment: I rolled back the edit inserting the answers in the question. The point of the Q&A format is to have the question at the top and the answers below.

Comment: Not an answer, because I am not sure, but I think of French *pile* as *cell* in English, and *batterie* as [*battery*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_(electricity)), which is two or more cells. (But it is true that in English even a single cell is sometimes called a battery.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Quelle est la différence entre une pile et une batterie ?

En France et quand ce mot s'applique à un équipement fournissant de l'électricité, ***batterie*** a commencé à être utilisé comme raccourci de ***batterie d'accumulateurs***, ensemble d'éléments rechargeables stockant et fournissant de l’électricité, utilisés en particuliers dans les véhicules.

Batterie indique ici que plusieurs éléments sont disposés côte à côte, à la manière d'une batterie de canons, terme ancien d'artillerie.

D'autre part, ***pile*** désigne à l'origine un ensemble de pièces empilées les unes sur les autres, d'où leur nom, qui produisent de l'électricité à la suite d'une réaction chimique, mais de façon non réversible contrairement aux accumulateurs. c.f. [Mémoire de Volta](https://www.bibnum.education.fr/physique/electricite-electromagnetisme/la-pile-de-volta): *n'est-il pas au surplus actif par lui-même sans aucune charge précédente, sans le secours d'une électricité quelconque excitée par aucun des moyens connus jusqu'ici*

Aujourd'hui, seule la capacité à être rechargées ou pas distingue ce que nous appelons en France d'une part les batteries (ou parfois les accumulateurs) qui sont rechargeables et d'autre part les piles qui sont à usage unique.

Stricto sensu, la plupart des piles ne sont pas des piles puisqu'elles ne contiennent qu'un seul élément, souvent de 1,5 V, et la plupart des batteries ne sont pas des batteries car elles ne contiennent elles non plus qu'un seul élément, souvent de 1,2 V. Les piles 4,5 V ou 9 V sont cependant de vraies piles au sens étymologique, ainsi que sont de vraies batteries celles qui alimentent nos appareils photos, téléphones, tablettes et autres ordinateurs portables.

De nombreux modèles de piles et de batteries sont d'aspect identique et sont généralement interchangeables dans les appareils qu'elles alimentent. Leurs dimensions sont normalisées et les plus courantes sont les "piles bâton" AAA/RC03,  AA/RC6 et C/RC14. Ceci entraîne souvent une confusion et certains appellent parfois abusivement, ou sans savoir exactement ce qui est réellement installé, piles les modèles rechargeables.

Dans le commerce, l'indication alcaline permet d'identifier la plupart des vraies piles (sauf les piles boutons qui sont à l'argent ou au mercure) alors que rechargeable ainsi que la technologie utilisée, le plus souvent Ni-MH, sont les indications qui apparaissent sur la plupart des accumulateurs.

> Quand on parle d'une pile ordinaire (de type AA, C, 9V, ...), peut-on utiliser le terme « batterie » ?

On ne devrait pas.

> Quand on parle d'une batterie de voiture 12V, peut-on utiliser le terme « pile » ?

Non, mais contrairement au cas de la question précédente, je n'ai jamais entendu personne commettre cette erreur.

> Des sites bilingues (comme walmart.ca) utilisent « batterie » quand on s'attend à ce qu'ils utilisent « pile ». Est-ce que les deux mots sont confondus dans le français canadien ?

Il s'agit d'un anglicisme, l'anglais utilisant *battery* dans les deux cas. Pour les distinguer, pile se traduit par *primary/disposable battery* et batterie par *secondary/rechargeable battery*.

Answer (score 6):

Le terme *batterie* est largement plus utilisé au Canada que *pile*. Les deux termes réfèrent à des objets différents, mais peu s'attardent à la différence.

Les piles produisent de l'électricité à partir d'une réaction chimique. On parle ici des piles alcalines, voltaïques, etc., comme les piles de montres ou les AA, C et 9V. En français canadiens, elles sont couramment appelées *batteries*.

Les batteries sont des ensembles d'éléments généralement montés en série qui génèrent de l'électricité, contrairement aux piles qui sont monoblocs. Il est donc *correct* de parler d'une batterie de voiture, qui d'ailleurs ne sera jamais appelée une *pile*. (Le terme *batterie* peut également être employé dans le sens de *batterie de cuisine*, de *batterie de tests*, de *batterie d'artillerie* et d'instrument de musique.)

Les piles devraient être appelées des piles, et non des batteries, comme le prescrit [cet article des Clefs du français pratique de Termium](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_b&page=9evjareGnJnI.html#zz9evjareGnJnI). Cependant, l'usage de *batterie* prédomine en français canadien, et Wal-Mart a décidé de se conformer au vocabulaire de ses clients plutôt qu'au vocabulaire français correct.

> Le mot *batterie* est un anglicisme au sens de **pile** :
>
> > J’ai acheté des piles AA pour ma lampe de poche.
>
> Le mot *batterie* est toutefois correct au sens d’« ensemble d’éléments générateurs d’énergie électrique » (accumulateurs, piles, condensateurs, etc.). Il est donc approprié de parler de batterie pour une voiture.

Comment: Est-ce qu'on parle de « piles rechargeables » au Québec ? Ce sont des objets qui ont la forme d'une pile (on les mets dans le même appareil), mais le comportement d'une batterie (elles stockent de l'énergie temporairement, contrairement aux piles traditionnelles dans laquelle l'énergie est consommée une fois pour toutes).

Comment: De manière générale on les appelle batteries, comme toutes les autres, mais il me semble avoir déjà vu *piles rechargeables* sur des emballages.

Answer (score 4):

En France, la distinction se fait sur la possibilité de les recharger ou non:

- les **piles** ne sont pas réutilisables. Ce sont des éléments de petite taille, bien qu'on en trouve parfois d'assez volumineuses (pour lampes puissantes). On trouve quelquefois *pile rechargeable*, mais c'est un mauvais emploi: voir termes suivants;
- les **batteries** sont rechargeables. C'est le terme utilisé pour une batterie de voiture;
- on employait il y a quelques dizaines d'années le terme **accumulateurs** (simplifiés en **accus**), notamment pour les formats identiques aux piles. Ce terme est nettement moins employé, et a été supplanté par batteries.

Pour des raisons de sécurité (risque de feu voire d'explosion), il est souvent indiqué sur les piles que celles-ci ne sont pas rechargeables. C'est peut-être une norme obligatoire.

Toutefois, pour éviter toute ambiguité, il est souvent précisé *pile jetable*.

L'expression *recharger ses batteries* signifie se reposer.

nota: l'emploi plus général de *batterie* étant "ensemble d'éléments, d'instruments", l'emploi du pluriel est abusif pour l'électricité. C'est certainement l'analogie avec *les piles* qui fait que l'on emploie *les batteries*.

Comment: Pas tout à fait : il existe des piles rechargeables, qui sont *stricto sensu* des batteries mais que personne n'appelle comme ça. En fin de compte la différence entre *pile* et *batterie* dans l'usage en France tient plus au format qu'à la technologie.

Comment: @Gilles oui, sauf que c'est un emploi incorrect, ce qu'on indique le plus souvent, c'est que les piles ne sont pas rechargeables. réponse modifiée.

Answer (score 1):

Les piles et accumulateurs électriques sont tous deux des générateurs électrochimiques. Une pile électrique est utilisable une fois (générateur primaire), la réaction électrochimique est irréversible ; un accumulateur électrique au contraire peut régénérer plusieurs fois les substances chimiques (générateur secondaire) en le rechargeant grâce à un chargeur qui force les électrons à circuler en sens inverse, afin de reformer les produits consommés lors de la décharge.

Dans un accumulateur, les rôles des anodes et cathodes s'inversent selon que l'appareil se décharge ou se charge. Pour obtenir des tensions élevées, on associe en série des éléments : une batterie est une association de plusieurs éléments d'accumulateurs.

*[source](http://www.officiel-prevention.com/protections-collectives-organisation-ergonomie/risque-chimique/detail_dossier_CHSCT.php?rub=38&ssrub=69&dossid=526)*.

Answer (score 0):

Dans mon usage quotidien, j'utilise pile pour tous les accumulateurs extractibles et dont je peux trouver des réassorts au supermarché du coin et j'utilise batterie pour tous les accumulateurs que je ne peux pas aisément extraire de son appareil ou dont le format est spécifique. En général, ces derniers sont rechargeables.

Si l'on s'en tenait au sens strict, [celui que Volta a imaginé](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pile_volta%C3%AFque), les batteries de voitures devraient être nommées piles.

Comment: Non, les batteries utilisées dans les voitures (= ensemble d'accumulateurs rechargeables) ne sont pas du tout ce que Volta à inventé (= la pile, un générateur à usage unique).

Comment: Ce que Volta a inventé, c'est une pile, comme une pile d'assiettes, autrement dit un ensemble de dispositifs produisant de l'électricité mis bout à bout. Le fait qu'elle soit rechargeable ou pas n'a rien à voir avec le nom qu'il lui a donné.

Comment: Non, la mise en série et les accumulateurs d'électricité (ex: bouteilles de Leyde) existaient déjà comme en atteste le mémoire que Volta a lui même rédigé pour décrire son invention: la pile voltaïque qui n'est pas rechargeable par conception. c.f. https://www.bibnum.education.fr/physique/electricite-electromagnetisme/la-pile-de-volta *n'est-il pas au surplus actif par lui-même sans aucune charge précédente, sans le secours d'une électricité quelconque excitée par aucun des moyens connus jusqu'ici*

Answer (score 0):

La plupart des gens n'ont aucune idée de la structure interne d'une pile/batterie. On appelle une pile cylindrique une pile, que cela soit rechargeable ou non. Les langues évoluent, même le français, et ce qu'on dit devient souvent ce qui est correct.

Comment: bienvenu dans french langage, votre réponse n'apport rien de plus à ce qui a été écrit il y a plus d'un an.